# How to avoid more than one continue statement in java

Tags: java

I'm using more than one continue statement in for loop but when i run sonar it is complaining too many continue statements.  Can you please help how to reduce to one continue statement? For example:

```
for() { 
     if(condition1) { continue } 
     if(condition2) { continue } 
     // more ...
}
```

Above is my code sample.

Comment: Can not see any `continue` statements here - please re-post using the `visible` font

Comment: Please post your complete code.. Depends upon ur requirements u may change your logic accordingly..
If your if condition is in pair of || or && (Logical Operator) 
eg if((condition 1)&&(condition2))  or
if((condition 1)&&(condition2)) 
Thn u should continue with the logic u used
Other wise switch case may be a solution if any string char int byte kind of data is to validate in IF statement

Comment: very bad edit of question. code segment contains a part of question description.

Comment: "too many continues" is a stupid rule.  turn it off

Comment: ``else if`` is best when all ``if`` followed by another. We could use a ``boolean`` variable when ``if`` are scattered . A demo at my answer...

Comment: Obviously it's a supid rule... If you want to replace by if/else statement, you'll find yourself with another complaint from Sonar => cognitive complexity.

Answer (score 4):

Using continue in every `if` mean you dont want to execute rest of your code. This simply mean you are trying to do similar work as `if else`. So put you code in `else` part which you dont want to execute after going into some `if` like this.

```
for() { 
 if(condition1) { 
    // your code
 } 
 else if(condition2) { 
    // your code
 } 
 // more ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `else if` is best solution when all `if` followed by another. We could use a `boolean` variable when `if` are scattered.

I think you are trying something like:

```
for() {
    //few more code     
    if(condition1) { 
        //few more code
        continue; 
    } 
    //few more code
    if(condition2) { 
        //few more code
        continue; 
    } 
    //few more code
    if(conditionN) { 
        //few more code
        continue; 
    } 
}
```

Then you should use by using a `boolean` variable

```
boolean needMoreExecution = true;
for() {     
    //few more code
    if(needMoreExecution && condition1) { 
        //few more code
        needMoreExecution = false; 
    }
    //few more code
    if(needMoreExecution && condition2) { 
        //few more code
        needMoreExecution = false; 
    } 
    //few more code
    if(needMoreExecution && condition_N) { 
        //few more code
        needMoreExecution = false; 
    } 
    //few more code
    if(needMoreExecution) { 
        //rest of the code of loop
    } 
}
```

Comment: for(i:n) { boolean condition1 = I determine condition1 here; if(condition1) { continue} boolean condition2=I determine condition2 here;  if(condition2) { continue } boolean condition3=I determine condition3 here; if(condition3) { continue } if none of the above condition satisfy then i add i to arraylist. al.add(i);

Comment: @user3492304 , Please update your code sample of question. It is not mentioning what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the context, but in general you can avoid using them at all by excluding them by **if (!(all of your conditions for continuing))** statement.

For example, your "code" would look like that

```
for(something in there) 
{ 
  if(!(condition1 && condition2)) 
    //do whatever you didn't want to be executed for those conditions 1 and 2. 
}
```

Also, if you would not write lots of ifs in one line, your code would be much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Use `if-else` statement so that you can have **only one statement** to be executed. Also consider multiple conditions in one statement is possible for avoiding such cases.

Comment: Thank you all. Above discussed helped me.

Comment: I decided to do like this:                                                                                          for(something in there) 
{ 
  if(!(condition1 && condition2)) 
    //do whatever you didn't want to be executed for those conditions 1 and 2. 
}